# How to italicize the heading and optional title of a theorem?

Tags: theorems

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \def\th@plain{
  \thm@notefont{}
  \itshape}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{prop}[Optional Title]
  Content.
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

I want to italicize the (bold) heading and (normal) optional title of the sample theorem (proposition).

Comment: Would you be willing to use a package such as `ntheorem` or `amsthm`?

Comment: Sure, I just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual style that you want to update is the `definition` style (since you specify it), like so:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \def\th@definition{
  \thm@headfont{\itshape} % Heading font is italic
  \thm@notefont{} % Note is same as heading
  \itshape% Regular text is also italic
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{prop}[Optional Title]
  Content.
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

#### Edit:

Note that the same result can be made with the `article` class by loading `amsthm` ... nearly all of the same code is used in both cases, so the same trick will apply in either setting.  From the [documentation](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf):

> Three document class files and one package file (amsthm.sty) are produced from
>   this source. Most of the code of the `amsthm` package is used in all four derived
>   files.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \def\th@definition{
  \thm@headfont{\itshape} % Heading font is italic
  \thm@notefont{} % Note is same as heading
  \itshape% Regular text is also italic
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{prop}[Optional Title]
  Content.
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See edit as well ; same effect is attainable with `article` (or other) class and `\usepackage{amsthm}` if that is what you prefer to use.

Comment: That should come in handy. I appreciate the detailed answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs the capabilities of the `ntheorem` package.

[image]

If you want the theorem's header separated from the body with, say, a "dot" (`.`), just add the instruction `\theoremseparator{.}` between the `\theoremheaderfont` and `\newtheorem` statements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\textit}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras]
Consider a right triangle with sides labelled $a$, $b$, and~$c$, and wlog assume that 
the longest side is labelled $c$. Then \[ a^2+b^2=c^2. \]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```